# Evaluating Multiple Classifier using f2 score

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am trying to classify some models in a binary classification. I want to classify the models with respect of score and f2 score.

For the 'score' I used the code

```
for name, clf in zip(models, classifiers):
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    score = clf.score(X_test, y_test)
    scores.append(score)
```

Which gives the scores of all the models, but I am not able to do it find the f2 score of all the models. Can anyone suggest what should be the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [fbeta_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.fbeta_score.html) for this where you just set β equal to 2.

```
from sklearn.metrics import fbeta_score

scores = []
f2_score = []

for name, clf in zip(models, classifiers):
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
    f2 = beta_score(y_test, y_pred, beta=2, average='binary')
    score = clf.score(X_test, y_test)
    scores.append(score)
    f2_score.append(f2)
```

Comment: How to define 'y_true' in this case.

Comment: @cris2019 apologies its supposed to be `y_test` which are the true labels.

Comment: @ yudhiesh One more question, if I use GridSearchCV and want to find the find f2 score for the each of the models, what should I do.  I want to display, the score and f2 score in a data frame.

Comment: ```scores = []

for model_name, mp in model_params.items():
    clf =  GridSearchCV(mp['model'], mp['params'], cv=5, return_train_score=False)
    clf.fit(X_test, y_test)
    scores.append({
        'model': model_name,
        'best_score': clf.best_score_,
        'best_params': clf.best_params_,
        'f2_score': fbeta_score(y_test, y_pred, beta=2, average='binary')
    })
    
df = pd.DataFrame(scores,columns=['model','best_score','best_params','f2_score'])
df```

Comment: @cris2019 hi please create a new question for this.